# Can I get $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ integrable when $g(x)\neq0$ for $f(x),g(x)$ is integrable

Tags: integration, analysis

Can I get $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ (meaning $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$ is
convergent)integrable when $g(x)\neq0$ for $f(x),g(x)$ is integrable?

When $g(x)\geq C>0$,  $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ is integrable. But if $g(x)$ is just infinitely closer to $0$ and there will be no constant to bound it except $0$ itself. I think in this condition it maybe cause the $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\rightarrow \infty$ so it may not integrable. Is my idea right? Or is there some other ideas about it?
Thank you!

Comment: You might find it helpful to consider $f(x) = 1$ and $$g(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 1 & \text{if } x = 0.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On $(0,1)$ take $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=x$. Then $\frac f g $ is not integrable.